# The JDK specification in maven Property section

Tags: java, maven

I am seeing a maven file containing this section:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.executable>${env.OPENSHIFT_WILDFLY_DIR}usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_05/bin/javac</maven.compiler.executable>
    <maven.compiler.fork>true</maven.compiler.fork>
</properties>
```

It seems to me it requires JDK 1.8 has to be installed, in order for the project to be built. However, only up to JDK 1.7 is installed on the machine. Could you explain why this works just fine? I am puzzled. Thanks.

Comment: Properties are just like constant variables. You can define as many properties as you want and those all properties will not be accounted if you don't specify them in you rest of the pom.xml. You better paste complete pom.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you have an executable specified which points to  1.8... could that explain the mystery?

Comment: It's a tutorial  and I downloaded as is. I don't understand it either. I am new to maven. It simply works. I don't understand why only Jdk 1.7 installed, but here it's specified as Jdk 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `maven.compiler.executable` property suggests that your project will be built on RedHat's OpenShift Cloud gear, and that gear likely has JDK 8 installed. As to why a project would run locally without issues, I would guess that it does not include any *.java files and as a consequence the compiler is never invoked.

Unless your demo requires Java 8, it should be fine to change 1.8 -> 1.7 and remove maven.compiler.executable property. Then Maven would invoke whatever javac you happen to have in the PATH.

Answer (score 0):

If you want Maven to check the JDK version, you need to use the Maven Enforcer Plugin: http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireJavaVersion.html